# Redirect old .html URLs to a new installation in a subfolder

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I have two WordPress installations, one under example.com and one under example.com/archive

I want to achieve this:

`example.com/something/something/article.html` has to redirect to
`example.com/archive/something/something/article.html`

Basically, URLs ending with ".html" have to be redirected to another wordpress installation located under `example.com/archive`. Under `example.com` I'll have a totally new website, so I don't want the redirect rules to mess with it.

How do I write this rule into my `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

Hey see the following link. It has information about redirecting from one site to another :
[Redirecting Your Site With .htaccess](http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-htaccess.phtml)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I know the basics but I find it difficult to write a good rule using regex expressions without interfering with the new wordpress installation. I'll edit my post to make in clearer.